# JavaFX: How to move "drop down arrow" in TitledPane to be on right

Tags: java, javafx, accordion, scenebuilder

I hope everyone is doing well.

I'm trying to move the drop down arrow in a TitledPane to be laid out on the right, instead of the left like it is by default. I'm using JavaFX 8, and many of the resources I've found don't seem to work.

I have found that I am able to move the arrow a specific amount, like 20 pixels shown below

```
.accordion .title > .arrow-button .arrow
{
    -fx-translate-x: 20;
}
```

But I want something responsive. Is there some way that I can get the width of the titled pane, and then subtract some pixels so that so that the arrow appears to be laid out on the right when resizing? Is there a better way to it? I added the element using SceneBuilder2 if that matters.

Thanks so much for your time.

Edit: The following was added for clarification

[image]
[image]

Primarily, I want the arrow to be right justified, like below

[image]
[image]

Instead of just "to the right" of the arrow. I really appreciate all the assistance.

Comment: Do you only want the arrow on the right or can the text be on the right as well?

Comment: Only the arrow. I would like the text to be left aligned. Thanks for your interest in another one of my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no public API for moving the arrow to the right side of the `TitledPane`. This doesn't mean this can't be accomplished, however, we just have to translate the arrow dynamically, using bindings. In order for the rest of the title area to look correct we'll also have to translate the text, and graphic if present, to the left. The easiest way to do all this is by subclassing `TitledPaneSkin` and accessing the internals of the "title region".

Here's an example implementation. It lets you position the arrow on the left or right side via CSS. It's also responsive to resizing as well as alignment and graphic changes.

```
package com.example;

import static javafx.css.StyleConverter.getEnumConverter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.css.CssMetaData;
import javafx.css.SimpleStyleableObjectProperty;
import javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty;
import javafx.css.StyleableProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TitledPaneSkin;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class CustomTitledPaneSkin extends TitledPaneSkin {

    public enum ArrowSide {
        LEFT, RIGHT
    }

    /* ********************************************************
     *                                                        *
     * Properties                                             *
     *                                                        *
     **********************************************************/

    private final StyleableObjectProperty<ArrowSide> arrowSide
            = new SimpleStyleableObjectProperty<>(StyleableProperties.ARROW_SIDE, this, "arrowSide", ArrowSide.LEFT) {
        @Override protected void invalidated() {
            adjustTitleLayout();
        }
    };
    public final void setArrowSide(ArrowSide arrowSide) { this.arrowSide.set(arrowSide); }
    public final ArrowSide getArrowSide() { return arrowSide.get(); }
    public final ObjectProperty<ArrowSide> arrowSideProperty() { return arrowSide; }

    /* ********************************************************
     *                                                        *
     * Instance Fields                                        *
     *                                                        *
     **********************************************************/

    private final Region title;
    private final Region arrow;
    private final Text text;

    private DoubleBinding arrowTranslateBinding;
    private DoubleBinding textGraphicTranslateBinding;
    private Node graphic;

    /* ********************************************************
     *                                                        *
     * Constructors                                           *
     *                                                        *
     **********************************************************/

    public CustomTitledPaneSkin(TitledPane control) {
        super(control);
        title = (Region) Objects.requireNonNull(control.lookup(".title"));
        arrow = (Region) Objects.requireNonNull(title.lookup(".arrow-button"));
        text = (Text) Objects.requireNonNull(title.lookup(".text"));

        registerChangeListener(control.graphicProperty(), ov -> adjustTitleLayout());
    }

    /* ********************************************************
     *                                                        *
     * Skin Stuff                                             *
     *                                                        *
     **********************************************************/

    private void adjustTitleLayout() {
        clearBindings();
        if (getArrowSide() != ArrowSide.RIGHT) {
            // if arrow is on the left we don't need to translate anything
            return;
        }

        arrowTranslateBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            double rightInset = title.getPadding().getRight();
            return title.getWidth() - arrow.getLayoutX() - arrow.getWidth() - rightInset;
        }, title.paddingProperty(), title.widthProperty(), arrow.widthProperty(), arrow.layoutXProperty());
        arrow.translateXProperty().bind(arrowTranslateBinding);

        textGraphicTranslateBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            switch (getSkinnable().getAlignment()) {
                case TOP_CENTER:
                case CENTER:
                case BOTTOM_CENTER:
                case BASELINE_CENTER:
                    return 0.0;
                default:
                    return -(arrow.getWidth());
            }
        }, getSkinnable().alignmentProperty(), arrow.widthProperty());
        text.translateXProperty().bind(textGraphicTranslateBinding);

        graphic = getSkinnable().getGraphic();
        if (graphic != null) {
            graphic.translateXProperty().bind(textGraphicTranslateBinding);
        }
    }

    private void clearBindings() {
        if (arrowTranslateBinding != null) {
            arrow.translateXProperty().unbind();
            arrow.setTranslateX(0);
            arrowTranslateBinding.dispose();
            arrowTranslateBinding = null;
        }
        if (textGraphicTranslateBinding != null) {
            text.translateXProperty().unbind();
            text.setTranslateX(0);
            if (graphic != null) {
                graphic.translateXProperty().unbind();
                graphic.setTranslateX(0);
                graphic = null;
            }
            textGraphicTranslateBinding.dispose();
            textGraphicTranslateBinding = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        clearBindings();
        unregisterChangeListeners(getSkinnable().graphicProperty());
        super.dispose();
    }

    /* ********************************************************
     *                                                        *
     * Stylesheet Handling                                    *
     *                                                        *
     **********************************************************/

    public static List<CssMetaData<?, ?>> getClassCssMetaData() {
        return StyleableProperties.CSS_META_DATA;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CssMetaData<?, ?>> getCssMetaData() {
        return getClassCssMetaData();
    }

    private static class StyleableProperties {

        private static final CssMetaData<TitledPane, ArrowSide> ARROW_SIDE
                = new CssMetaData<>("-fx-arrow-side", getEnumConverter(ArrowSide.class), ArrowSide.LEFT) {

            @Override
            public boolean isSettable(TitledPane styleable) {
                Property<?> prop = (Property<?>) getStyleableProperty(styleable);
                return prop != null && !prop.isBound();
            }

            @Override
            public StyleableProperty<ArrowSide> getStyleableProperty(TitledPane styleable) {
                Skin<?> skin = styleable.getSkin();
                if (skin instanceof CustomTitledPaneSkin) {
                    return ((CustomTitledPaneSkin) skin).arrowSide;
                }
                return null;
            }

        };

        private static final List<CssMetaData<?, ?>> CSS_META_DATA;

        static {
            List<CssMetaData<?,?>> list = new ArrayList<>(TitledPane.getClassCssMetaData().size() + 1);
            list.addAll(TitledPaneSkin.getClassCssMetaData());
            list.add(ARROW_SIDE);
            CSS_META_DATA = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        }

    }

}
```

You can then apply this skin to all `TitledPane`s in your application from CSS, like so:

```css
.titled-pane {
    -fx-skin: "com.example.CustomTitledPaneSkin";
    -fx-arrow-side: right;
}

/*
 * The arrow button has some right padding that's added
 * by "modena.css". This simply puts the padding on the
 * left since the arrow is positioned on the right.
 */
.titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button {
    -fx-padding: 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em 0.583em;
}
```

Or you could target only certain `TitledPane`s by adding a style class and using said class instead of `.titled-pane`.

The above works with JavaFX 11 and likely JavaFX 10 and 9 as well. To get it to compile on JavaFX 8 you need to change some things:

- Import `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TitledPaneSkin` instead.

  - The skin classes were made public in JavaFX 9.
- Remove the calls to `registerChangeListener(...)` and `unregisterChangeListeners(...)`. I believe replacing them with the following is correct:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void handleControlPropertyChange(String p) {
      super.handleControlPropertyChange(p);
      if ("GRAPHIC".equals(p)) {
          adjustTitleLayout();
      }
  }
  ```
- Use `new SimpleStyleableObjectProperty<ArrowSide>(...) {...}` and `new CssMetaData<TitledPane, ArrowSide>(...) {...}`.

  - Type inference was improved in later versions of Java.
- Use `(StyleConverter<?, ArrowSide>) getEnumConverter(ArrowSide.class)`.

  - There was a bug in the generic signature of `getEnumConverter` that was fixed in a later version. Using the cast works around the problem. You may wish to `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` the cast.

**Issue:** Even with the above changes there's a problem in JavaFX 8—the arrow is only translated once the `TitledPane` is focused. This doesn't appear to be a problem with the above code as even changing the `alignment` property does not cause the `TitledPane` to update until it has focus (even when not using the above skin, but rather just the default skin). I've been unable to find a workaround to this problem (while using the custom skin) but maybe you or someone else can. I was using Java 1.8.0_202 when testing for JavaFX 8.

---

If you don't want to use a custom skin, or you're on JavaFX 8 (this will cause the arrow to be translated without needing to focus the `TitledPane` first), you can extract the necessary code, with some modifications, into a utility method:

```
public static void putArrowOnRight(TitledPane pane) {
    Region title = (Region) pane.lookup(".title");
    Region arrow = (Region) title.lookup(".arrow-button");
    Text text = (Text) title.lookup(".text");

    arrow.translateXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        double rightInset = title.getPadding().getRight();
        return title.getWidth() - arrow.getLayoutX() - arrow.getWidth() - rightInset;
    }, title.paddingProperty(), title.widthProperty(), arrow.widthProperty(), arrow.layoutXProperty()));
    arrow.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em 0.583em;");

    DoubleBinding textGraphicBinding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        switch (pane.getAlignment()) {
            case TOP_CENTER:
            case CENTER:
            case BOTTOM_CENTER:
            case BASELINE_CENTER:
                return 0.0;
            default:
                return -(arrow.getWidth());
        }
    }, arrow.widthProperty(), pane.alignmentProperty());
    text.translateXProperty().bind(textGraphicBinding);

    pane.graphicProperty().addListener((observable, oldGraphic, newGraphic) -> {
        if (oldGraphic != null) {
            oldGraphic.translateXProperty().unbind();
            oldGraphic.setTranslateX(0);
        }
        if (newGraphic != null) {
            newGraphic.translateXProperty().bind(textGraphicBinding);
        }
    });
    if (pane.getGraphic() != null) {
        pane.getGraphic().translateXProperty().bind(textGraphicBinding);
    }
}
```

*Note: While this puts the arrow on the right without having to focus the `TitledPane` first, the `TitledPane` still suffers from the issue noted above. For instance, changing the `alignment` property doesn't update the `TitledPane` until it's focused. I'm guessing this is simply a bug in JavaFX 8.*

This way of doing things is not as "easy" as the skin approach and requires two things:

1. The `TitledPane` must be using the default `TitledPaneSkin`.
2. The `TitledPane` **must** have been displayed in a `Window` (window was *showing*) **before** calling the utility method.

   - Due to the lazy nature of JavaFX controls, the skin and the associated nodes will not have been created until the control has been displayed in a window. Calling the utility method before the control was displayed will result in a `NullPointerException` being thrown since the `lookup` calls will return `null`.
   - If using FXML, note that the `initialize` method is called during a call to `FXMLLoader.load` (any of the overloads). This means, under normal circumstances, it's not possible for the created nodes to be part of a `Scene` yet, let alone a showing `Window`. You must wait for the `TitledPane` to be displayed first, *then* call the utility method.

     Waiting for the `TitledPane` to be displayed can be achieved by listening to the `Node.scene` property, the `Scene.window` property, and the `Window.showing` property (or you could listen for `WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN` events). However, *if you **immediately** put the loaded nodes into a showing `Window`*, then you can forgo observing the properties; call the utility method inside a `Platform.runLater` call from inside `initialize`.

When using the skin approach, the whole wait-for-showing-window hassle is avoided.

---

*Usual Warning: This answer relies on the internal structure of `TitledPane` which may change in a future release. Be cautious when changing JavaFX versions. I only (somewhat) tested this on JavaFX 8u202 and JavaFX 11.0.2.*

Comment: When I tested this solution in a controlled way, it worked flawlessly in my local environment. However, I tried to apply it to my project, wherein the only difference is that I defined the accordion in FXML using SceneBuilder, instead of instantiating in code. When I apply the code to an accordion, I get a NPE on: 

'Region arrow = (Region) title.lookup(".arrow-button");'

Do you know why that's happening perhaps? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm doing it in the controller on initialize just to add detail.

Comment: Updated answer to address FXML.

Comment: @TerryDorsey I updated my answer to provide a more robust example. However, at its core it still simply translates the arrow to the right.

Comment: nice answer :) Wondering why you use both StyleableProperty and PseudoClass? btw, the support for styleableProperty was simplified (don't know which version) by StyleablePropertyFactory.

Comment: @kleopatra Hm, good question. I think I just got carried away and didn't think it through completely. As for `StyleablePropertyFactory`, I haven't used it in a while but I remember being disappointed with it. Especially with the fact all the methods return `StyleableProperty` rather than the specific abstract classes. For instance, if it returned `StyleableIntegerProperty` one could expose the property as an `IntegerProperty`. Instead, you get a `StyleableProperty<Number>` which, I believe, ends up using `SimpleStyleableObjectProperty` as the implementation.

Comment: yeah, have been there ;) The factory methods for the property are often useless (particularly when we need to hook into the invalidated), but personally, I still let the factory create and manage the cssMetaData: that reduces the styleSheet handling block to a couple of lines. My preference only, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t exactly the same, visually, but you can hide the arrow button and create a graphic that acts like an arrow button.  TitledPane extends Labeled, so you have control over the placement of the graphic relative to the text, via the [contentDisplay](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#contentDisplayProperty) property.

First, hide the arrow button in the stylesheet:

```
.accordion .title > .arrow-button
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

In the code, you can create a Label to act as a fake button and set it as the TitledPane’s graphic.  The entire title line is sensitive to the mouse, so an interactive control (like a Button) is not needed.

```
Label collapseButton = new Label();
collapseButton.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.when(titledPane.expandedProperty())
        .then("\u25bc").otherwise("\u25b6"));

titledPane.setGraphic(collapseButton);
titledPane.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
```

Comment: While this solution appears  functional, the arrow appears just to the right side of TiteldPane text, instead of all the way to the right of the titled pane. Is there a way to modify what you have here to get that effect? Like a region that always hgrows?

Comment: @TerryDorsey The [documented TitledPane structure](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane) claims the Node with class `title` is an HBox, so yes, it should have been possible to add the Label rather than passing it as a TitledPane graphic… but when I tried it, I discovered that the `title` Node is actually a subclass of StackPane.  Manipulating it, or its children, might work, but could easily break in a future (or past) version of JavaFX, since there is no guarantee as to what the child Nodes will be.

Answer (score 0):

In FXML you can just add nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT"
or use yourNode.setNodeOrientation​((NodeOrientation orientation)
[https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setNodeOrientation(javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setNodeOrientation(javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation)))