# JavaFX: refer to collapsed and expanded accordion states in CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, accordion

I hope everyone I doing well.

I'm trying to control the arrow's rotation based on its `collapsed` or `expanded` psuedo-class property in my TiteldPane objects using css. I'm using javafx8. If you look at the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane), you will see that `expanded` and `collapsed` psuedo-classes are there.

Below is a minimal example of what I would think should work. 
A generic main ->

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;


public class Main extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        Accordion accordion = new Accordion
        (
                new TitledPane("TitledPane #1", new Label("Content #1"))
        );
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(accordion, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And the css below works on the main as you would expect ->

```
.accordion .title > .arrow-button
{
    -fx-rotate: -45;   
}
```

But if I want to affect the arrow's rotation on the basis of whether it is collapsed, I would expect to be able to write something like below ->

```
.accordion .title:collapsed > .arrow-button
{
      -fx-rotate: 45;
}

.accordion .title:expanded > .arrow-button
{
      -fx-rotate: -45
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work and show how it should be done correctly? In the project I'm trying to apply this to, I'm not animating the rotation, but I'd be interested to know if that affects things.

Thank you so much for taking the time to assist me.

EDIT: Adding detail to what I want to achieve specifically. I want the arrow to point down in the collapsed state, and I want it to point upwards in the expanded state.

Comment: The pseudo class applies to the `TitledPane`, not part of the substructure (i.e. `.title`). What if you try `.titled-pane:collapsed > .title > .arrow-button { ... }`?

Comment: Also the "standard" rotation happens on the `.titled-pane:collapsed > .title > .arrow-button > .arrow` node, but you cannot adjust the rotation of that one, since the `rotate` property of that node is bound... Applying a rotation to the `.arrow-button` node just makes the whole thing look weird, but in that case you'd only need to set the difference between the desired rotation and the actual rotation: `.accordion > .titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button { -fx-rotate: 45; }`

Comment: @Slaw I found that your snippet allowed me to referred to the arrow in it's collapsed state, but I was not able to rotate it, as the comment below yours states, mentioning that it is bound, but I was able to affect other things, like visibility.

Comment: @fabian I have a little bit of trouble understanding what you mean by `actual rotation` but I think you mean the amount that it rotates between states? I'm sorry I don't get you 100%. Your css allowed me to turn the entire node, but the difference stays 90 degrees. Just to add some detail to what I'm seeking, I want the arrow to point down in the collapsed state, and I want it to point upwards in the expanded state. It naturally turns 90 degrees between states, but I am trying to achieve a 180 degree difference between the two states. Question updated to reflect.

Comment: Since the arrow's rotate property is bound, we can only rotate the arrow-button. The problem is that rotating the arrow-button adds to the arrow's rotation—resulting in the arrow's "actual rotation". You'd need to rotate the arrow-button an amount that takes the arrow's rotation into account. Been messing around with this for a couple minutes, but alas... I can't get the padding to look right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around with this some more, I found a hack that allows you to point the arrow down when collapsed and up when expanded. However, it won't work properly when the `TitledPane` is animated (or at least looks bad).

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;

public static void pointArrowUp(TitledPane pane) {
    Region arrow = (Region) pane.lookup(".arrow");

    Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
    rotate.pivotXProperty().bind(arrow.widthProperty().divide(2.0));
    rotate.pivotYProperty().bind(arrow.heightProperty().divide(2.0));
    rotate.angleProperty().bind(
            Bindings.when(pane.expandedProperty())
                    .then(-180.0)
                    .otherwise(90.0)
    );

    arrow.getTransforms().add(rotate);
    pane.setAnimated(false);
}
```

Just like with [my answer to a previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55085777/6395627), the above requires the `TitledPane` to have been displayed in a `Window` before use; that is, unless you utilize a custom skin.

I tried simply calling `arrow.rotateProperty().unbind()` then setting the rotation in CSS, but for whatever reason I couldn't get it to look right.

---

*Usual Warning: This is a "hack" and relies on the internal implementation of `TitledPane` and its skin which may change in a future release. Be careful when changing JavaFX versions. I only tried the above with JavaFX 11.0.2.*

Comment: Thank you so much. This functions great. However `I want the arrow to point down in the collapsed state` is the inverse of how that code functions. It points up when collapsed and down when expanded, but this is easily edited to suit what I want.

Comment: Edited my answer. Must have switched that around in my head for some reason.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you for the edit and the answer :)

Comment: Also works with javaFX15. I added this to your custom control skin class in the constructor and it works as well.